# Vue router lazy loading routes not working

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I used Vue CLI and building an spa.

In `router.js` I try:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: "",
      name: "home", 
      component: Home
    },
    { 
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      component: () => {
       import ("./views/About")
    } 
    },
    { 
      path: "/contact",
      name: "contact",
      component: () => {
       import ("./views/Contact")
      } 
    }
  ]
})
```

But my router links and routing is not working anymore?

From here I [read](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) that I have to install `syntax-dynamic-import`? But how do I add that plugin `webpack.config.js`? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Try returning the import from the function:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: "",
      name: "home", 
      component: () => import("./views/Home")
    },
    { 
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      component: () => import("./views/About") 
    },
    { 
      path: "/contact",
      name: "contact",
      component: () => import("./views/Contact")
    }
  ]
})
```